# D3.js - how to use result in previous step

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get total amount, total price, and average price in one D3 nest statement. How can I use total amount and total price? I am using D3 V4.11.

```
  var closedByType = d3.nest()
  .key(function (d) { return d.type; })
 .rollup(function(v) {
    return {

      amount: d3.sum(v, function(d) {return d.amout}),
      price: d3.sum(v, function(d) {return d.price})
      //averagePrice = Total price /total amount --How can I do it?
    }
    })
  .entries(items);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store `amount` and `price` in variable and then return the complete result object.

Try simply this :

```
var closedByType = d3.nest()
  .key(function (d) { return d.type; })
  .rollup(function(v) {
    amount= d3.sum(v, function(d) {return d.amout})
    price = d3.sum(v, function(d) {return d.price})
    return {    
      amount: amount,
      price : price, 
      averagePrice : price / amount
    }
  })
  .entries(items);
```